# Are there models for QCD confinement in non supersymetric theories?

Tags: condensed-matter, string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, beyond-the-standard-model, confinement

I was reading Shifman papers about QCD confinement. He usually use methods from condensed matter and string theory to solve the problem using the gauge/string.

Is there some similar approach from condensed matter but without requiring supersymmetry? or is there other theorical approach at all (not lattice)?

Source: https://arxiv.org/find/hep-th/1/au:+Shifman_M/0/1/0/all/0/1